# Prove that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.

Tags: order-theory

I would like to prove the following statement.

A nonempty subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval "if and only if" $x$, $y$ $\in E$ and $x<z<y$ imply $z$ $\in$ $E$.

Proof of one direction:
Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $E$ is an interval. By way of contradiction, suppose $x$, $y$ $\in$ $E$ and $x<z<y$, but $z$ $\notin$ $E$. Since $E$ is an interval and $x$, $y$ $\in$ $E$, $[x,y]$ $\subset$ $E$. Moreover, since $x<z<y$, $z$ $\in$ $[x,y]$. Thus, $z$ $\in$ $E$, which is a contradiction.

Is the above proof correct? In addition, I cannot prove the opposite direction. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: The proof is [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interval_Defined_by_Betweenness).

Comment: Don't feel dumb…the proof is non-trivial. Just read whichever textbook you are using or the link provided by DHMO. If you can understand that, you are good enough. This result is an important lemma for using the notion of connectedness to prove the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: your proof is correct. However, it is going to be hard to prove the other way unless you have an alternate definition of 'interval' which you can use. The general form would be: Assume $x,y \in E \land x<z<y \Rightarrow z\in E$ AND $E$ is not an interval and try to reach a contradiction. However, this is where you need another definition of 'interval'. Good luck!

Comment: What is your definition of an interval?  Notice that the given condition of convexity includes not only bounded intervals but also rays and R itself.  Do you consider R or (0,oo) an interval?

Comment: @jorgeegroj That is exactly what I thought: I would need an alternative definition of an interval in order to prove the other direction. I will surely try to find other definitions so that I can prove this statement. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @William Elliot We consider $\mathbb{R}$. Unfortunately, we did not really cover the definition of an interval. Instead, I learned that for real numbers a and b with a<b, [a,b], [a,b), (a,b], (a,b), [a,$\infty$), (a,$\infty$), (-$\infty$,b], (-$\infty$,b), or (-$\infty$,$\infty$) is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DHMO Thank you so much. Now that I read the proof, I understand how to prove this. Thank you again so much!

Comment: @Li Chun Min Now that I read the link provided by DHMO, I can prove the statement. I will make sure to remember this lemma when I prove the intermediate value theorem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TimLee.  By your description of an interval, they are connected, hence convex.  Conversly show convex subsets of R are connected and the only connected subsets within R are the intervals you listed.  Hint, consider the sup and inf of a connected set and if they are in the set.  That is a lot of cases.